# HTML5 Geolocation - display content when at a certain location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geolocation

I'm trying to get to grips with the geolocation capabilities in HTML5.

I am seeing a lot of 'find your position' help around, but I'm trying to make it so that content on my website (in this case, a video) only becomes available if the user is at a certain location, within specific coordinates

Any help is very much appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using one of the many 'find your position' tutorials you've found (e.g. [finding your position with Geolocation](http://html5doctor.com/finding-your-position-with-geolocation/)), use `watchPosition`, and when it's the position you want (however you want to figure that out) then display your content.

Oh and Geolocation is not part of HTML5, it's a separate specification.